# How To Connect PHP7.3, sql server & Nginx Debian10

Tags: sql-server, nginx, debian, php-7

Please help me....

I've created a web server using OS Debian 10, Nginx and PHP7.3 and everything is running well. but when it will connect to the sql server, it cannot connect.

I've done several tutorials such as:

1. pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
2. Follow steps mentioned on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15
3. File .ini driver
   `root@debian:~# ls /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/*sqlsrv.ini /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-sqlsrv.ini /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini root@debian:~#`
4. my php info:
   [image: phpinfo]
5. my script and result in browser like :
   [image: script connect]

so please help me to solve this problem, Thank you Very Much

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full and complete error message - as text. Your screen shot of part of an error message is missing a lot of potentially important information. Also related: which specific version and edition (Express, Developer, Standard, Enterprise) of SQL Server are you attempting to connect to? Is it the default instance (e.g: someHost\MSSQLSERVER) or a specific named instance (e.g.: someHost\Test01)? If it's a named instance what port is it running on, do you have the SQL Browser Service running and is udp/1434 open on the firewall to support that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having issues with the client on Debian 10 with OpenSSL1.1.1 the fix is to revert to the previously default weaker key length. To do so:

Modify

```
/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

config file as follows

Change the last line from

```
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2
```

to

```
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

(fyi see known issues with OpenSSL 1.1.1 in Debian 10 below):

https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1021

https://wiki.debian.org/ContinuousIntegration/TriagingTips/openssl-1.1.1